# Db Search - Multiple conditions

Tags: lotus-domino, lotus

I am trying to export Documents from a Lotus DB. I have used the Db.search functionality and arrived at below code. However, I want to include 2 conditions/functions - @Contains & @Created together. I am getting Formula error. Any help is much appreciated.

```
      Set GlobalCollection = db.Search("@Created > [01/01/2019]" & " " & "@Contains(" & "App1" & ";" & """Approved""" & ")", Nothing, 0)
```

Comment: I cannot use FTSearch as it gives index error.

Comment: If you are getting an index error, you should try to fix that. Rebuild the FT index, for example. Don't just let the index error be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The escape symbol for LotusScript is a backslash, `\`. LotusScript allows you to use more than just double quotes to wrap Strings. You can use curly braces (`{...}`) or pipes (`|...|`). This may make it more readable and easier to trubleshoot. There's also no need to have separate strings for each individual piece, which will again minimise risk and help readability. There may have been a mistake with each of those, I'm pretty sure you're missing an ampersand. It's much easier to troubleshoot with fewer strings.

So this should work:

`Set GlobalCollection = db.Search({@Created > [01/01/2019] & @Contains(App1;"Approved")}, Nothing, 0)`

Comment: I had misplaced an ampersand (&).